# how to show "yyyy / mm / dd" as initial in forms.DateField

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to show the string "YYYY/mm/dd" as the default value for a forms.DateField and treat that as an empty value, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way? Use HTML5 `placeholder` attribute (with JS support if you need to support browsers that don't support `placeholder`). You can pass it inside `attrs` argument of the widget constructor.